# Renaming months from number to name in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

i have the following dataframe:

```
High    Low Open    Close   Volume  Adj Close   year    pct_day
month   day                             
1   1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2010.0  0.000000
2   7869.853149 7718.482498 7779.655014 7818.089966 7.471689e+07    7818.089966 2010.0  0.007826
3   7839.965652 7719.758224 7775.396255 7777.940002 8.185879e+07    7777.940002 2010.0  0.002582
4   7747.175260 7624.540007 7691.152083 7686.288672 1.018877e+08    7686.288672 2010.0  -0.000744
5   7348.487095 7236.742135 7317.313616 7287.688546 1.035424e+08    7287.688546 2010.0  -0.002499
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
12  27  7849.846680 7760.222526 7810.902051 7798.639258 4.678145e+07    7798.639258 2009.5  -0.000833
28  7746.209996 7678.152204 7713.497907 7710.449358 4.187133e+07    7710.449358 2009.5  0.000578
29  7357.001540 7291.827806 7319.393874 7338.938345 4.554891e+07    7338.938345 2009.5  0.003321
30  7343.726938 7276.871507 7322.123779 7302.545316 3.967812e+07    7302.545316 2009.5  -0.000312
31  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2009.5  0.000000
```

Since it is not clear from the above pasted dataframe, below is a snapshot:

[image]

The months are in 1,2 3 ... Is it possible to rename the month index to Jan Feb Mar format?

Edit :

I am having a hard time implementing the example by @ChihebNexus

My code is as follows since it is a datetime :

```
full_dates = pd.date_range(start, end)
data = data.reindex(full_dates)
data['year'] = data.index.year
data['month'] = data.index.month
data['week'] = data.index.week
data['day'] = data.index.day
data.set_index('month',append=True,inplace=True)
data.set_index('week',append=True,inplace=True)
data.set_index('day',append=True,inplace=True)
df = data.groupby(['month', 'day']).mean()
```

Comment: @Raju Could you please elaborate i am not sure what you mean by replace command

Comment: @newcoder, can you give a better idea of your dataframe? It looks like your year is an integer and month and day are indices. I would suggest to create a date from those 3 columns and extract the month name from that new column using `strftime`. Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes.

Comment: df.replace({'month': {1:' jan', 2: 'feb',....}})

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do it using calendar and pd.CategoricalDtype to ensure sorting works correctly.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import calendar

#Create dummy dataframe
dateindx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31', freq='D')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000, (len(dateindx), 5)), 
             index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([dateindx.month, dateindx.day]),
             columns=['High', 'Low','Open', 'Close','Volume'])

#Use calendar library for abbreviations and order
dd=dict((enumerate(calendar.month_abbr)))

#rename level zero of multiindex
df = df.rename(index=dd,level=0)

#Create calendar month data type with order for sorting
cal_dtype = pd.CategoricalDtype(list(calendar.month_abbr), ordered=True)

#Change the dtype of the level zero index
df.index = df1.index.set_levels(df.index.levels[0].astype(cal_dtype), level=0)
df
```

Output:

```
        High  Low  Open  Close  Volume
Jan 1    501  720   671    943     586
    2    410   67   207    945     284
    3    473  481   527    415     852
    4    157  809   484    592     894
    5    294   38   458     62     945
...      ...  ...   ...    ...     ...
Dec 27   305  354   347      0     726
    28   764  987   564    260      72
    29   730  151   846    137     118
    30   999  399   634    674      81
    31   347  980   441    600     676

[365 rows x 5 columns]
```

Answer (score 4):

For example, if we could have this DataFrame, we could use `datetime` package within this [`datetime format table`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) like this example:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(range(1, 13), columns=['month']) 
df['month'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: '{:%b}'.format(datetime.strptime(str(row['month']), '%m')),
    axis=1
) 
print(df)
```

Output:

```
0    Jan
1    Feb
2    Mar
3    Apr
4    May
5    Jun
6    Jul
7    Aug
8    Sep
9    Oct
10   Nov
11   Dec
```

**Update:** As @Ch3steR suggested. You're using a `MultiIndex` DataFrame.
So, here is an example how you can modify it's first level index:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

tuples = [(1, 10), (1, 12), (1, 13), (2, 1), (2, 20), (2, 10)]
index  = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['month', 'day'])
serie = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(tuples)), index=index)
df = pd.DataFrame(serie, columns=['data']) 

print(df)

               data
month day          
1     10  -0.463804
      12   1.979072
      13   0.087430
2     1    0.928077
      20  -0.697795
      10  -0.275762

idx = pd.Index(df.index).get_level_values(0)
# Set new index, but keep the multindex levels
df = df.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(((
        '{:%b}'.format(datetime.strptime(str(k), '%m')), 
        v 
) for k, v in idx), names=['month', 'day']), ['month', 'day']) 
print(df)

               data
month day          
Jan   10  -0.463804
      12   1.979072
      13   0.087430
Feb   1    0.928077
      20  -0.697795
      10  -0.275762
```

**Update2:**

I see that you've hard time to implement my answer into your code. This is why i've making this update to show you how you can implement my code within the code snipped you've added to your question. This is an example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd


start = '1/4/2020'
end = '3/5/2020'

data = pd.DataFrame()
full_dates = pd.date_range(start, end)
data = data.reindex(full_dates)
data['year'] = data.index.year
data['month'] = data.index.month
data['week'] = data.index.week
data['day'] = data.index.day
data.set_index('month', append=True, inplace=True)
data.set_index('week', append=True, inplace=True)
data.set_index('day', append=True, inplace=True)
df = data.groupby(['month', 'day']).mean()
idx = pd.Index(df.index).get_level_values(0)
df = df.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(((
    '{:%b}'.format(datetime.strptime(str(k), '%m')),
    v
) for k, v in idx), names=['month', 'day']), ['month', 'day'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
           year
month day      
Jan   4    2020
      5    2020
      6    2020
      7    2020
      8    2020
...         ...
Mar   1    2020
      2    2020
      3    2020
      4    2020
      5    2020

[62 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: OP has `multiIndex` where level 0 is month level 1 is a day. He updated the question with clear photo.

Comment: He can use [`df.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) and specify the level as 0 and provide a dict for conversion like `{0:'Jan',1:'Feb',...}`

Comment: @Ch3steR Thanks for your comments. For the `multiIndex` i'll add another example how the OP can deal with them. And `YES`, `rename` can be a solution but, personally, i'll not use it in a program in production. I'll be a pain to maintain such a list ... If you know what i mean.

Comment: Yes, totally agreed. That's why I added it as comment. Extracting level 0 index can be done using [`pd Index.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html)

Comment: @Ch3steR See my update. Better using `set_index` with a comprehension

Comment: @ChihebNexus thank you for your detailed answer. I am still working through it, quick question, why is `pd.Index` and not `df.Index`? It works but curious why is I in index not capalized for df? I am very new to coding so forgive my lack of understanding

Comment: `pd.Index` let's us have an `Immutable ndarray implementing an ordered, sliceable set` witch give us access to the function `get_level_values` that returns the multindex levels by their ids. Like what the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) says.

Comment: @newcoder  `df.index` => Access to the column `index` in your DataFrame. `pd.Index` is a method/function under pandas framework & utilities.

Comment: @ChihebNexus My multiindex level 0 is `datetime` field but yours is `tuple` what should i do?

Comment: @ChihebNexus I have added my code could you please advise how can i implement your suggestion to this?

Comment: @newcoder you have to use the first datafrtame you added to your example then use my answer from `idx` line part...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214025/discussion-between-new-coder-and-chiheb-nexus).

Comment: there is no 30th of February ;-) (at least not at the moment, but who knows...)

Comment: @MrFuppes yes it was just an example. Also, i don't check the dates i convertes only the months. But, yoy're right i'll fix my example. Thanks for pointing out this typo.

Comment: @newcoder See my update. I've added an example using your code snippet you gave in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Converting month numbers to names is easy with `dt.month_name` in `pandas.Series`, ie.:

```
pd.to_datetime(np.arange(12)+1, format='%m').to_series().dt.month_name().str[:3].values
```

Output:

```
array(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep',
       'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'], dtype=object)
```

It is a bit more complicated if you want to use it to update your index, because `pd.MultiIndex` is an immutable type. It should be possible though to add new columns with month names and days in your data frame, and then replace the old index with the new one, ie. given that 'month' and 'day' are the 0th and 1st index levels in your dataframe:

```
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index.levels[0], formatt='%m').to_series().dt.month_name().str[:3]
df['day'] = df.index.levels[1]
df.set_index(['month', 'day'], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually think using built-in datetime attributes (as described by mac13k) is the most pythonic solution, or simply extracting the month before creating your df as suggested in the comments by Raju.

However, if you need more flexibility in your index re-labelling you can use the [`.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) method of a pd.DataFrame to rename the level 0 index.

As an example which should work directly on your df:

```
# set up df to match format of question
month = np.arange(1, 13)
day = np.ones(len(months))
a = np.zeros(len(months))
df = pd.DataFrame({'month':month, 'day':day, 'a':a})
df = df.set_index(['month', 'day'])

# create personalised mapping to rename index
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
month_map = {i+1:month for i, month in enumerate(months)}

# rename the level 0 index
df.rename(index=month_map, level=0, inplace=True)
```

which edits the df in-place to yield:

```
               a
month   day 
Jan     1.0   0.0
Feb     1.0   0.0
Mar     1.0   0.0
Apr     1.0   0.0
May     1.0   0.0
Jun     1.0   0.0
Jul     1.0   0.0
Aug     1.0   0.0
Sep     1.0   0.0
Oct     1.0   0.0
Nov     1.0   0.0
Dec     1.0   0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try importing calendar, creating a dictionary mapping from number -> name and then apply that mapping.