# Interpreting Multiindex datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, multi-index

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import matplotlib
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

start = datetime.date(2020,1,1)
end = datetime.date.today()

stock =  'fb'

data = web.DataReader(stock, 'yahoo', start, end)
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format ='%Y-%m-%d')
data = data[~data.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
data['year'] = data.index.year
data['month'] = data.index.month
data['week'] = data.index.week
data['day'] = data.index.day
data.set_index('year', append=True, inplace =True)
data.set_index('month',append=True,inplace=True)
data.set_index('week',append=True,inplace=True)
data.set_index('day',append=True,inplace=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=300, figsize =(30,4))
data.plot(y='Close', ax=ax, xlabel= 'Date')

plt.show()
```

[image]

What can I do to interpret the multiindex dates as the x axis in more readable year and month format? Such as in a format like `strftime('%y -%m')`. A similar question was asked here: [Renaming months from number to name in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61842649/renaming-months-from-number-to-name-in-pandas)
But I am unable to see how I can use this to rename the x axis. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **dates** from **matplotlib**. See the following link for more details:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.ConciseDateFormatter

Here is the modified code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import matplotlib
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

from matplotlib import dates as mdates

start = datetime.date(2020,1,1)
end = datetime.date.today()

stock =  'fb'

data = web.DataReader(stock, 'yahoo', start, end)
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format ='%Y-%m-%d')
data = data[~data.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
data['year'] = data.index.year
data['month'] = data.index.month
data['week'] = data.index.week
data['day'] = data.index.day
data.set_index('year', append=True, inplace =True)
data.set_index('month',append=True,inplace=True)
data.set_index('week',append=True,inplace=True)
data.set_index('day',append=True,inplace=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=300, figsize =(15,4))
plt.plot(data.index.get_level_values('Date'), data['Close'])

#--------------------------------------
#Feel free to try different options
#--------------------------------------
#locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
locator = mdates.MonthLocator()

formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.show()
```

Here is the
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwuO1.png).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dawn. It has improved my understanding also! :)