# Highlighting Date Range

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to highlight a section of the plot using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import matplotlib
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

from matplotlib import dates as mdates

start = datetime.date(2020,1,1)
end = datetime.date.today()

stock =  'fb'

data = web.DataReader(stock, 'yahoo', start, end)
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format ='%Y-%m-%d')
data = data[~data.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
data['year'] = data.index.year
data['month'] = data.index.month
data['week'] = data.index.week
data['day'] = data.index.day
data.set_index('year', append=True, inplace =True)
data.set_index('month',append=True,inplace=True)
data.set_index('week',append=True,inplace=True)
data.set_index('day',append=True,inplace=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=300, figsize =(15,4))
plt.plot(data.index.get_level_values('Date'), data['Close'])
plt.axvspan((datetime(2020,3,12)), (datetime(2020,6,1)), 
            label="Labeled",color="green", alpha=0.3)
```

The format is should be `matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan(xmin, xmax, ymin=0, ymax=1, **kwargs)` as per the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan.html) . Could you please advise how can I get the values for y_min and y_max?

```
locator = mdates.MonthLocator()


formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.show()
```

I am trying to make the plot look like this: [image]
https://datavizpyr.com/highlight-a-time-range-in-time-series-plot-in-python-with-matplotlib/

[Interpreting Multiindex datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70321364/interpreting-multiindex-datetime/70324619#70324619)

Comment: The default values for ymin and ymax are 0 and 1, so the entire vertical area of the graph will be filled. If you want to specify values, you can specify the minimum and maximum values for the period. Is this a good answer?

Comment: I am trying to enter a value such as y_min = 200 or leave it blank but i am getting the following error: `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`. How can i resolve this? Thanks

Comment: I thought I could use transforms, but axvspan was fixed. So the following code can be used to calculate ymax when the maximum value of the y-axis is 200. `x0,x1 = ax.get_ylim();offset = 200;new_max = (offset - x0) / (x1 - x0);ax.axvspan(...,ymax=new_max)`

Comment: @r-beginners Thanks for your help. What if i want it to calculate the ymax which spans the max height? So the entire region would be covered regardless of the ticker i use?

Comment: It is the maximum value of the closing price, so in the previous example, replace x1 (the maximum of the graph area) with `df['Colse'].max()`.

Comment: The maximum value is the height of chart. I have included the link in the question, the author of that tutorial did not include the ymax yet it covered the plot height, in my case I am getting `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import matplotlib
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

from matplotlib import dates as mdates

start = datetime.date(2020,1,1)
end = datetime.date.today()

stock =  'fb'

data = web.DataReader(stock, 'yahoo', start, end)
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format ='%Y-%m-%d')
data = data[~data.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
data['year'] = data.index.year
data['month'] = data.index.month
data['week'] = data.index.week
data['day'] = data.index.day
data.set_index('year', append=True, inplace =True)
data.set_index('month',append=True,inplace=True)
data.set_index('week',append=True,inplace=True)
data.set_index('day',append=True,inplace=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=300, figsize =(15,4))
ax.plot(data.index.get_level_values('Date'), data['Close'])
y0,y1 = ax.get_ylim()
offset = data['Close'].max()
new_max = (offset - y0) / (y1 - y0)
ax.axvspan((datetime.datetime(2020,3,12)), (datetime.datetime(2020,6,1)), 
            label="Labeled",color="green", alpha=0.3, ymin=0, ymax=new_max)

plt.show()
```

[image]